# how can i update multiple images in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update multiple images on laravel, the old images will be automatically deleted from storage after the update.

I try implementing this using the update method below:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $listing = Listing::where('id', $id)->first();
    
    $listing->title = $request->get('title');
    $listing->price = $request->get('price');
    $listing->address = $request->get('address');
    $listing->rooms = $request->get('rooms');
    $listing->city = $request->get('city');
    $listing->state = $request->get('state');
    $listing->zip_code = $request->get('zip_code');
    $listing->area = $request->get('area');
    $listing->balcony = $request->get('balcony');
    $listing->bedrooms = $request->get('bedrooms');
    $listing->bathrooms = $request->get('bathrooms');
    $listing->toilet = $request->get('toilet');
    $listing->bathroom_type = $request->get('bathroom_type');
    $listing->kitchen = $request->get('kitchen');
    $listing->parking_space = $request->get('parking_space');
    $listing->description = $request->get('description');
    $listing->featured = $request->get('featured');
    $listing->status = $request->get('status');
    $listing->type = $request->get('type');
    $listing->water_supply = $request->get('water_supply');
    $listing->power_supply = $request->get('power_supply');

    if($request->hasFile('images') != ''){    
        
        $listingImage = ListingImage::findOrFail($id);    
        //add new image
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
            $image = $request->file('images');
            $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
            $oldImagepath = $listingImage->image_path;
            // Update the database
            $listingImage->image_path = $imageName;
            // Delete the old photo
            Storage::delete($oldImagepath);
            $listingImage->save();
            $image->move(public_path('images/listing/'.$listing->id),$imageName);
        }
    }

    $listing->save();
    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Listing updated!');
}
```

but I got the error **Error
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array**. My images are being stored in the ListingImage model and I have configured the default filesystem to

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('images/listing/'),
```

what steps can i take to achieve updating new images in my laravel application

Answer (score 2):

in the `foreach loop` you are using `$request->file('images')` which is wrong and you are assigning it to `$image` variable it should be:

```
foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
         // remove this line of code
         $image = $request->file('images');
        $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $oldImagepath = $listingImage->image_path;
        // Update the database
        $listingImage->image_path = $imageName;
        // Delete the old photo
        Storage::delete($oldImagepath);
        $listingImage->save();
        $image->move(public_path('images/listing/'.$listing->id),$imageName);
    }
```

Comment: I try to delete the foreach loop but I still got the same error. please could you explain more

Comment: no don't need to remove foreach loop, only delete the line $image = $request->file('images')

Comment: thanks that fixed the **Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array** issue but my new image did not display, I still get the old images

Comment: are you getting new images in database?

Comment: let me show you some sample code in the answer and you customize it for yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220356/discussion-between-toby-nwude-and-naveed-ali).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you change `$image->getClientOriginalExtension()` instead of `$image->file('images)->getClientOriginalExtension()`.

Second you save **multiple images** in column like this `["first_image.jpeg", "second_image.jpeg"]`

```
$images = [];
foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
      $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      //save images in public/images/listing folder
      $image->move(public_path('images/listing/'), $imageName);
      // Delete the old photo
      $oldImagepath = $listingImage->image_path;
      Storage::delete($oldImagepath);
      $images[] = $imageName;
      $json_encode = json_encode($images);
      $listingImage->image_path = $json_encode;
}

$listingImage->save();
```

Comment: The image_path wasn't stored in the database. Just the imageName was stored

Comment: I saw this `image_path` and I thought this was image path. Try to use my code. It works fine.

Comment: Check `dd($listingImage);` before `foreach` and show me result;